# activemq, slowdown fast producer

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there in activeMQ any way to 'tell' producer to slowdown if all consumers are considered as a slow consumers, but in situation if only few of consumers are 'slow' to drop their(those slow) connection using AbortSlowConsumerStrategy ?

Answer (score 0):

Producer Flow Control will force a producer to stop (not slow down, but stop and wait) until a message has been consumed before it's allowed to send another message, but there's nothing that's able to throttle producers to a lower-but-not-stopped rate.  And certainly nothing to take a census of all the consumers and determine whether they're all slow or just some of them and react accordingly.